# Objective-C generics - is there a way to make the generic match the class (in cases of inheritance)

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch, generics

I have `ClassA` and `ClassB`, and I'd like to make `ClassB` inherit from `ClassA` to streamline my code. The problem is that almost everything is shared except that for `ClassA` I have a generic array like so:

```
@property NSMutableArray<ClassADataType*> objectsArray;
```

whereas for `ClassB` I have a generic array:

```
@property NSMutableArray<ClassBDataType*>
```

Similarly for `ClassA` I have a property of a single class instance like so:

```
@property ClassADataType* object
```

and for `ClassB` I have a property like so

```
@property ClassBDataType* object
```

`ClassBDataType` inherits from `ClassADataType`, and similarly I would like to make `ClassB` inherit from `ClassA`. Is there a way to do this, basically overriding a class property of the class from which a class inherits?

Answer (score 3):

No, this would violate [Liskov Substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle), particularly because these are mutable properties as written. For example:

```
ClassA *a = [ClassB new]; // Legal and proper because B is an A.
a.object = [ClassADataType new]; // "Legal," but completely broken.
```

(If they were immutable properties, in principle this kind of feature could exist without creating these problems, but ObjC doesn't provide the feature even in that limited case, and it's hard to prove a property is *always* readonly in ObjC.)

In most cases the right answer is not to use inheritance. Generally it is better to handle shared code through composition (helper objects) rather than class hierarchies. This is especially true since you say this is "to streamline my code." You should never create inheritance unless you can say "in all ways, a B is a more specific kind of A." It's not good enough to say "they have a lot of code in common."

If you really do need to use inheritance, the common technique is to add another property to B that downcasts.

```
@property (readonly) ClassBDataType* classBObject;

- (ClassBDataType *) classBObject {
    return (ClassBDataType *)self.classAObject;
}
```

It is very important in this case that these properties be readonly to the outside world, or else you can get the inconsistencies mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer by Rob. I have had similar cases and I think there could be a case for inheritance, however if B is not a direct descendant from A I have found the best pattern is an abstract class baseAB that both A and B inherits from and that has all the shared code.

For the typed array property then each subclass can have it's own, but that is probably not so good as then a lot of code cannot move to the base class. Depends on how central this array is to the class.

The option then could be to put a generic array property in the base class with a shared ancestor of the `ClassADataType` and `ClassBDataType`, but that may defeat the idea of typing the array.

Or you could skip the generics for the array, make it an iVar of the base class and provide custom typed methods in the subclassess to set and get values and do the type checking.